# VBA copiando data padrão brasileiro em padrão americano

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Tenho o código abaixo em uma macro, para copiar um arquivo TXT separado por ponto e vírgula para um arquivo Excel:

```
Sub Atualizar_Dados()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Abre o arquivo do servidor (mudado para txt ao inves de csv)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://pcn-sig.peccin.local/sig/ebsout/txt/pcnopmrelrefugos_mail.txt"
    Columns("A:U").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows("BASE ORACLE - Teste Hora.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("BASE").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    'colar especial
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Seleciona a coluna com os dados
    Columns("A").Select
    'Ativa a função texto para coluna
    Selection.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=True, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:=";"

    'Ativa o arquivo aberto do servidor
    Windows("pcnopmrelrefugos_mail.txt").Activate
    'Fecha o arquivo
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Sheets("CAPA").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

O arquivo TXT, por exemplo, está com a data assim:

> ;12/11/18 21:21:42

Mas essa mesma linha, no Excel, fica assim:

> 11/12/2018 21:21

Inclusive, no Excel as datas ficam com formatações diferentes, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já deletei a coluna no Excel e criei outra, mas não resolveu. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se por ventura alguém passar por esse problema (TexttoColumns alterando o formato da data), segue abaixo a solução. Alterei a forma de copiar o CSV e deu certo. Mudei a chamada da função, mas isso não tinha alterado nada até copiar o CSV de forma diferente:

```
Sub Atualizar_Dados()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Abre o arquivo do servidor (mudado para txt ao inves de csv)
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    "http://pcn-sig.peccin.local/sig/ebsout/txt/pcnopmrelrefugos_mail.txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, Local:=True
    Columns("A:U").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows("BASE ORACLE - Teste Hora.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select

    'colar especial
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=";", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    'Ativa o arquivo aberto do servidor
    Windows("pcnopmrelrefugos_mail.txt").Activate
    'Fecha o arquivo
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente editar os padrões de data do seu computador no painel de controle ou no código adicione a formatação dos dados na coluna com:

```
Sheets("CAPA").Select
Range("B2", "B50000").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

Comment: a data da maquina é padrão PT-BR. E o number format não deu certo...

Comment: A fórmula Text(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy") funciona na planilha para formatar?

Comment: Não, por que a alteração acontece na função TextToColumns, se uso essa fórmula não muda nada pq já esta no formato...